# Interprocess communication with messages under linux

Tags: linux, pipe, ipc, message-queue

So basically, I have 5 processes, which are communicating like this - the 5th process sends its PID to the 4th, the 4th sends its own PID and the 5th's PID to the 3rd process and so on, and in the end the 1st process shows the PIDs of all the other processes. I've done the communication via pipes communication:

```
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>             
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int pid,pid1,pid2,pid3;
    int fd[2],fd1[2],fd2[2],fd3[2];
    pipe(fd);
    if( (pid = fork()) != 0 ) { //parent      
      int temp[5];
      close(fd[1]);
      read(fd[0],&temp,sizeof(temp));
      temp[0]=getpid();
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    printf("%d\n",temp[i]);
      }
      wait(); //wait for the child to complete
    }
    else { //child
      pipe(fd1);
      if( (pid1 = fork() ) != 0 ) {  //parent
    int temp[5];
    close(fd1[1]);
    read(fd1[0],&temp,sizeof(temp));
    temp[1]= getpid();
    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1],&temp,sizeof(temp));
    wait(); 
      }
      else { //child
    pipe(fd2);
    if( (pid2 = fork() ) != 0 ) {  //parent
      int temp[5];
      close(fd2[1]);
      read(fd2[0],&temp,sizeof(temp));
      temp[2]= getpid();
      close(fd1[0]);
      write(fd1[1],&temp,sizeof(temp));
      wait();
    }
    else { //child
      pipe(fd3);
      if( (pid3 = fork() ) != 0 ) {  //parent
        int temp[5];
        close(fd3[1]);
        read(fd3[0],&temp,sizeof(temp));
        temp[3]= getpid();
        close(fd2[0]);
        write(fd2[1],&temp,sizeof(temp));
        wait();
      }
      else { //child
        int temp[5];
        temp[4] = getpid();
        close(fd3[0]);
        write(fd3[1],&temp,sizeof(temp));
      }
    } 
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

But I have hard time doing the communication via messages. I can provide more information if needed. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Well, if you actually want to discuss messages rather than pipes, it'd be wise to talk about messages specifically, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, that is what I'm asking. I provided what I've done so far, for the purpose if someone suggests something or provides some kind of assistance, it would be easier for me to understand how it works.

Comment: Well, the code you've provided isn't about messages, that's what I've pointed out. Demonstrate your code with messages, explain, what problems you've got with it and I'm sure you'll get relevant help

Comment: "I have a hard time" isn't a valid description of the problem. Please state what you've tried, what you observe, what error messages you are getting, etc. And it helps to have a question instead of just asking for suggestions.

Comment: Why not just use something like rabbitmq, or if that's a bit overhead, some library like boost for inter-process communication...